# Python reading file, summing upp score

Tags: python, file

I have a file containing multiple rows. in the form of:

```
Name2 lastname2 0\n                             
Name1 lastname1 1\n           
Name2 lastname2 2\n                 
...
...
...
```

The file contains the same name a lot of times the number afterwards is a score.

I want to add all the points for one person and output the one with the highest score in total. I got a hint:

> Read each line and split the line in name and score. Then use a dictonary to map to the points.

I can split it, but I don't see how the dictionary helps? Could someone please explain and do an example of the mapping. (Not giving me the answer but the understanding).

Comment: So how would you track a score *per name*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a compelment to das-g's answerm: at last, use this to find the entry with highest score.

```
..
d = {'name1':1, 'name2':2}
max_value = max(d.values())
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    if value == max_value:
        print key
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the hint wants you to add up the scores while looping over the lines (or while reading them one by one) and to keep track of the scores in a dictionary like so:

- Have a (initially empty) dictionary mapping persons (identified by full name) to a score.
- Then, for each line:

  - If the person for this line is already in the dictionary, add this line's score to the existing one for that person.
  - Else, put person and score from this line into a new entry in the dictionary.

Comment: This is probebly the way to go. I will try to create a solution on this. This made sense, thanks!